# Firefox add-on to shorten a URL with bitly and give it a name

Tags: firefox, url-shortening

Firefox has a feature in which you right-click a link and it copies it to your clipboard.  I am looking for something that does even more than that.

With bitly you can **name** links, for instance you can decide that your URL should become `bit.ly/helloworld` for instance.

What I am looking for is an add-on which allows you to sign into bitly, and then when you right-click a URL, gives you the option to **name** the bit.ly link, and it goes into your account specifically.